# Help with understanding the usage of the command "equery has"

Tags: gentoo

```
equery has portage
!!! Fatal error: Used ENV_VAR without match_expression or --package
```

There is no description in http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Gentoolkit

On the other hand man page says it is not working fully yet. However how could I get sensible output? And to understand ENV_VAR (no description in man) , EAPI.. 
To operate the command with this module fluently I need several examples.

```
equery has bash
!!! Fatal error: Used ENV_VAR without match_expression or --package
```

The same result with others (even man page) equery has repository ....

Comment: *how* are you trying to run it? `equery has repository`, like all the other examples in the manpage, seems to require the actual value you're filtering for, for example `equery has repository sunrise` will list all installed packages whose repository (overlay)  is `sunrise`.

Comment: But I don't understand the meaning of the command.

Comment: It has three examples: EAPI 2, repository, and SLOT 2.4. There is none of them in short help. Secondly, I don't see any packages in this one--shot help. And thirdly you haven't help not with examples nor it seems that noone understand the command. Now i'm in the search between the internet in it

Comment: Imagine only 33 results "equery has" site:forums.gentoo.org (((

Comment: How are you running `equery has`? I provided you a working example, `equery has repository sunrise`, of course that, if you didn't install any package from sunrise, then you won't get any result for that. There's not much to be understood, IMHO. The command looks for *installed* packages that have the *specified* variable with the *specified* value. If you provide these two parameters, it is more likely to work than if you try to do `equery has bash`, if `bash` is even a possible option. If you want another example, `equery has SLOT 3` will show installed packages which are part of a slot "3".

Comment: In the end, try to run the two examples I provided you with, *then* say whether they work or not, they should. Then, if you don't understand what does each of them do, ask. There's nothing that complicated to be understood about this, IMHO. Most of this is about variables in the ebuild scripts, and other parameters portage records.

Comment: Thank you. Okay, I was, running, equery has. Man description: "List all installed packages that have a given PKG match." Well, for such a very green novice as me, it was counterintuitive (packages with values or environments). Along with specialized portage's functions dbapi.(), vardb etc.... So you were as right as rain  about variables in the ebuild scripts. Although after reading sove lines in man 5 ebuild I realized I need to read more.. But see:

Comment: `code` equery has LICENSE freedist
* Searching for LICENSE freedist..
[IP-] [  ] media-fonts/cronyx-fonts-2.3.1-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] media-fonts/freefonts-0.10-r3:0
[IP-] [  ] media-fonts/nepali-fonts-1-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] media-fonts/zh-kcfonts-1.05-r3:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-3.5.7:3.5.7 equery has --portage-tree RESTRICT userpriv
* Searching for RESTRICT userpriv ... 
[-P-] [  ] app-laptop/tp_smapi-0.40-r1:0
[-P-] [  ] dev-db/firebird-2.0.3.12981.0-r6:0
[-P-] [  ] games-board/gnuchess-book-1.01:0
[-P-] [ ~] games-fps/quakeforge-0.5.5-r2:0
[-P-] [ ~] games-rpg/wastesedge-0.3.4:0
`code`

Comment: `code` equery has RDEPEND "x11-libs/libX11"
 * Searching for RDEPEND x11-libs/libX11 ... 
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/dbus-1.6.8:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-apps/groff-1.21:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-auth/consolekit-0.4.5_p20120320-r1:0
[IP-] [  ] www-client/elinks-0.12_pre5-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-apps/xauth-1.0.7:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-apps/xclock-1.0.6:0
[IP-] [  ] x11-apps/xinit-1.3.2:0
`code`

Comment: equery has RESTRICT strip
 * Searching for RESTRICT strip ... 
[IP-] [  ] app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-baselibs-20120520:0
[IP-] [  ] app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-opengl-20120520:0
[IP-] [  ] app-emulation/emul-linux-x86-xlibs-20120520:0
[IP-] [  ] app-text/iso-codes-3.37:0
[IP-] [  ] dev-lang/nacl-toolchain-newlib-0_p9093:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-kernel/linux-headers-3.4-r2:0
[IP-] [  ] sys-libs/glibc-2.15-r3:2.2

Comment: cat $(find /usr/portage -name *.ebuild) | grep RESTRAINT - helped very well. Looks like it searches through variables inside .ebuild files! am i right in guessing

Comment: ebuilds are basicly scripts, emerge works mostly like that, it interprets ebuilds like BASH would interpret bash scripts; ebuilds can also inherit from some eclasses, which, in turn, may set some more variables. So yeah, I expect this to be mostly a variable search (hence the idea of "has XXX with value YYY").

Comment: I's a pity that no answer. I could do it from your and mine comments. Like organize an answer.